# How can I retrieve an answer I posted for a question that has been voluntarily removed by the author?

Tags: support, feature-request, deleted-questions

I recently posted an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973443/passing-through-mongodb-document-value-to-ejs-table) and I saw today that the question was voluntarily removed by its author. It's a bit disappointing because I wanted to reference the question and my answer, and now both are gone. Is there any way of accessing at least my own answer to that question? I have searched around, but I haven't found any way of doing so and I haven't been saving my Stack Overflow answers elsewhere, although if them disappearing is a possibility, perhaps I should. Some of them take considerable time to write up and would be great reference for the future. I would hate to lose them if someone removes their question.

Comment: Really making a case here for preventing users from deleting questions the moment they have any answers at all.

Comment: I've undeleted the question.  A question can be prevented from deletion if anyone in the community casts a single upvote on the answer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, thanks. Is there any way to consider what BoltClock said about preventing users from deleting questions as soon as an answer is posted?

Comment: @JuanCarlosFarah: The OP deleted his question several hours after you posted your answer, so I doubt that a deletion moratorium would have helped here.  Any likely upvotes on your answer should have been received within several minutes after the question was bumped when you posted your answer

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I understand that for my post there was a time gap and no upvotes. However, I do think that the following scenario that is not highly unlikely. Say a user spends a considerable time writing an answer, posts it and then, for whatever reason, the original question is removed, causing the user to "lose" his answer. I think there is a debatable point here that should be considered when decided when to prevent questions from being deleted.

Comment: I feel your pain.  I've had it happen several times that a fairly extensive answer was lost because the question was closed or deleted *before* I hit "Post Answer".  And in other cases had very nice answers get hidden by deletions after posting.

Comment: Let's have a badge that gets *taken away* if you ever reference one of your own questions or answers on meta.  Let the naming contest begin...

Comment: @BoltClock Or just let answerers view their answers even if the question is deleted. (of course preventing deleting questions can prevent deletion of crap answered by whores, motivated by downvotes; but can also prevent deletion of good questions/answers, like this)

Comment: @RobertHarvey, that is only a reasonable expectation on higher traffic tags. The tag I'm most interested in at the moment gets maybe 5-8 questions a week. They always intersect with more popular tags, but it's not unusual for a reasonable question and a correct answer to be completely ignored.

Comment: I have experienced that too. OP ask a question (which is valid and non-dup). I provided an answer which OP found really helpful. OP +1 my answer and accepted; All cool. Night when I logged back on SO, found that OP has deleted the post entirely; which I have no idea why he/she have done that? Since I didn't had the URL couldn't track the answer at all. Kind a same 3 more scenario happened. Don't understand why OP deletes the post; if that's the intent then why posting at all. Can Moderator do anything about it, to prevent?

Comment: My guess is that users deleting their own questions with answers are almost surely trying to prevent their classmates from getting the benefit of the same answer or trying to prevent their instructor from seeing that they asked SO. This kind of anti-social behavior should result in a ban from the site.

Comment: @R.., Totally agree cause answering those question is waste of time and effort. Moreover, at the end of day it doesn't serve any purpose.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Since answers must receive upvotes to preserve the question, I think it's reasonable to allow some period of time after an answer is posted to allow the community to vote on it, before a question that receives an answer is eligible for deletion by the OP.

24 hours seems like a reasonable period of time (or the question/answer score goes negative, whichever comes first).

Comment: Your suggestion is a great start, but doesn't address the really infuriating scenario where you are writing an answer, and find the question is closed before you post it (see @hotlicks's comment above).

Comment: That's a different problem.

Comment: @Floris Not a problem, if you are attempting to answer a bad question, you deserve the pain.

Comment: @user2371861 Those aren't necessarily bad questions.  I've run into morons who delete because the answer solved their problem (or perhaps they managed to solve it otherwise).

Comment: I think the 24 hour moratorium on deleting your question is a great thing. I have seen a few times (once this week) where someone has said in the comments that they won't bother coming back to mark an answer as "accepted". So those would be the perfect people to block from eliminating answers that could really help other people.

Comment: @bjb568, A user can delete his own question even if it's a good one.

Comment: @Pacerier Yes. I was replying to the case where it's closed.

Answer (score 7):

Did you check if the post shows up in "recently deleted" on "Answers" view of your profile?

I'm not sure if all answers show up there or only your own deletion + community once.

EDIT: Apparently this is only useful for 10K+ (as lower reputation users can't see *deleted questions*). I think it is sad, but looks like request to show all "my deleted answers" already rejected as discussed here [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted)

Comment: You have 10K+, so you can see deleted posts. Us below 10K can only see our own deleted posts, so if it was not our own question, we cannot see anything.

Comment: @Deduplicator - thanks - inlined your comment. It feels like unfortunate fallout of not being able to see deleted answers... And looks like by design (see linked discussion).

Comment: This solves the problem directly without changing anything outside. +1

Comment: @Deduplicator - Darn, guess it's going to be awhile before I'm allowed to see deleted things. I'm at 2.6K in 3.1 years... so I have another 9 years or so before I'm allowed to see deleted content (assuming a linear rate, which is laughably wrong).