# How to handle when OP deletes question when someone answered?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I see sometimes on Stack Overflow OP deletes the question once someone answered the question. I know OP can't delete the question once answer gets any one upvote but problem happens when there is no upvotes on answer.

New users don't know about this that system can block to ask next new question on Stack Overflow but what about who answered and spent ~10 minutes to write stuff.

Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267017

Answer (score 5):

If you feel the question and answer would be useful to others besides the OP, flag the question for moderator attention (chose 'other' and explain). If the moderator agrees they'll undelete the question.

This does assume you still can see the question; if you have <10k that may be problematic. If you still have the URL to the page, flag *another* post with the other flag (one by that user or one of your own posts) and explain that you cannot see the specific question but would still like to have it undeleted. Alternatively, find a 10k+ user in chat and ask them to flag the post for you; this also helps in getting a second opinion.

Comment: Related feature-requests: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261666/only-allow-questions-to-be-deleted-if-a-downvoted-answer-or-no-answer-is-present http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155933/preventing-misuse-of-question-self-deletion

Comment: FYI - Unless you took note of the asker's username you cannot view it again on the deleted question URL.

Answer (score 3):

A question that has no answers or only one answer with no up-votes isn't really that good a question so it's no great loss to the site. So if the OP decides to delete there's nothing to stop them doing just that regardless of how long it took someone to write the answer. If anything it's an argument for waiting a while before answering.

When you delete a down-voted question you are now presented with a dialog that says something along the lines of:

> Are you sure you want to do this? Deleting questions can mean that you won't be able to ask more questions in future.

(I've only ever seen this dialog once so I can't remember the details).

so users are discouraged from deleting.

Unless the criteria change to just questions that have no answers, then you are always going to run this risk.

Comment: Yup you are right but think about suppose op posted the question and just got the answer in 5 minutes then OP immediately deleted the question then ?? your case seems ok when question is old

Comment: @TGMCians - hence my point about waiting a while before answering. Though you won't get the first answer badges if you wait too long ;)

Comment: hahaha but people are quick here so can't wait bcz..:)

Comment: Isn't there a feature-request for enforcing a no-delete policy for a short time after a response was posted?

Comment: I've had this happen more than once, Chris; a good enough question being deleted as soon as the OP has their answer. In *less frequented tags* it can easily happen that the answer has yet to receive an upvote.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - maybe a feature request to change the deletion criteria is needed then - so it's only questions that are truly unanswered that can be deleted by the OP.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: See here for such feature-requests: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261666/only-allow-questions-to-be-deleted-if-a-downvoted-answer-or-no-answer-is-present http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155933/preventing-misuse-of-question-self-deletion

Comment: @ChrisF: Those feature requests already exist, as Deduplicator points out.

Comment: I think there should be time limit. OP should be able to delete the question only after 10/15 minutes ? This gives the community enough time to upvote/downvote an answer based on the quality.

Comment: @Shyju most of the time that's enough time for a question to get either an upvoted answer or multiple answers, both of which prevent the OP deleting their question.