# Restoring a good question deleted by its author after receiving an answer

Tags: discussion, support, new-users, vote-to-undelete

I recently answered a new member's question about an issue with their Java code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75109212/problem-with-breaking-and-continuing-a-loop-in-java but after they thanked me for solving their issue, they deleted the question (and my answer with it)! I think this is obviously a case where this new member does not know how this site is supposed to work: once you get an answer, you don't just delete the question, but you accept the answer and possibly even upvote it. So I'd like to request the question be restored.

The question was pretty specific so I know it's unlikely that anyone else will have that exact same problem (although variations of it exist, I'm sure), but it had some working code which wasn't entirely trivial, and it was, in general, just a well asked question. So this is not as much about the question and answer as it is about encouraging people to participate. If you spend a good chunk of your time answering someone in good faith, you certainly won't do it again if your work will just get deleted immediately.

Why do new members even have the right to just immediately delete their questions, especially if they've got answers, just like that, instead of requesting a deletion from some moderator, with justification?

Comment: "The question was pretty specific so I know it's unlikely that anyone else will have that exact same problem" This really isn’t a strong case for undeletion then. Deletion also implies there were no upvotes by anyone. What would be the benefit in keeping the Q&Q?

Comment: This sounds like an "I want more rep" post to me

Comment: "Why do new members even have the right to just immediately delete their questions, especially if they've got answers, just like that, instead of requesting a deletion from some moderator, with justification?" In fact, there [are limitations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403802/ive-rethought-my-question-about-a-homework-assignment-why-cant-i-get-it-delete).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi You did not fully read my question: "this is not as much about the question and answer as it is about encouraging people to participate". Why would I answer a question if it and the answer will just get deleted because a new user doesn't know the correct action is to accept the question and move on, instead of deleting it?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Well what's the point in answering all these questions here if you get exactly nothing out of it? Should I just not have answered it when I noticed that I could actually help the person who asked the question? How do I determine which questions are worth answering? Remind you, this was a well formed question with enough details to properly answer it.

Comment: You answered the question, OP found your answer helpful thus you did your job. The question belongs to the OP so they are within their right to delete. Imaginary internet points aren't the purpose of this site, they are just a nice side effect

Comment: @ZeroOne I did fully read your question, I just don't consider "participation" to be worth keeping around useless questions. You *did* participate whether the question sticks around or not. If you want your content to stick around, focus on answering questions worth keeping.

Comment: So "participation" is not something that should be especially encouraged on a site based on people voluntarily helping each other? I must say I don't agree with that sentiment.

Comment: @ZeroOne Participation *on content unlikely to be useful to others*? No, that indeed does not seem like something to be encouraged.

Comment: Well the thing is that it's always impossible to know what's going to be useful and what's not. Even if it's unlikely, it's still not impossible.

Comment: @ZeroOne *"Well what's the point in answering all these questions here if you get exactly nothing out of it?"* - distraction from work would be my honest answer. "Feeling like you made a difference" would be my romanticised answer. Whichever is the truth, I ain't doing it for fake internet points.

Comment: I don't agree with the reopening of this question, at best it falls under this closure reason IMO - "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo - While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers."

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Once posted on Stack Overflow, under the CC-BY-SA-n.m-... licence, the question does **not** "belong to the OP". It belongs to the Site and its community.

Comment: @AdrianMole I've seen somewhere about OP still having final say over their posts but I can't seem to find the reference to that, so I will agree to disagree with you on that point. I did however just find this "So if the OP decides to delete there's nothing to stop them doing just that regardless of how long it took someone to write the answer." https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267782/7147233

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flag it for moderator attention.  Use the custom flag ("in need of moderator intervention") and explain the situation and what you want the moderator to do.  Generally speaking, if a user posts a question and receives an answer, it is impolite and not appropriate to delete the question afterwards.  Moderators might be willing to undelete the question, if you ask for it.

Comment: Thank you. I flagged it and the question was restored.

Answer (score 10):

The question originally had two answers. That [would have prevented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) it being deleted by the question author, however the other answerer deleted their answer, thereby allowing the post author to delete the question.

If your answer had received any upvotes that would also have prevented the question being deleted as then we'd have evidence that the answer was useful to someone else.

Saying that it's unlikely that anyone else would have that same problem isn't making much of a case for undeletion. Those are the posts we want, the ones that do help lots of other people. Try to stick to answering those, as long as they aren't duplicates and then you'll have a much better case for undeletion. You could flag your answer for moderator attention and ask that the question be undeleted, but you'd need to give a better justification than you have so far.

As to why a question with a single answer can be deleted, it's because the community hasn't determined that it's useful. Maybe it was a typo and the answer just pointed that out, maybe the answer was wrong etc.

In fact the comment on your answer does suggest that it wasn't what the question asker wanted and they then realised that they hadn't put the necessary information in the question to allow it to be answered in the way that they wanted. I suspect that's why they deleted it.

> ... The thing is, if you look at the short video I added to my problem, that I want it to start at the left side, then shoot all ducks on the way to the right side of the screen, then move back to the left side and continue all over again - shoot all ducks, move to the right and after a short period of time, go back to left...

Comment: "In fact the comment on your answer does suggest that it wasn't what the question asker wanted" -- I beg to disagree: "Oh you are right, it will launch that scheduled executor so many times that it never stops", they said, which is exactly what I suggested.

Comment: As far as I see the question also did not even get to exist for long enough for its usefulness to the community to be determined. Do we only want to keep those questions that get a floor of upvotes immediately?

Comment: Sure, but you selectively quoted all the parts that support your world view and omitted all the parts that don't. "The thing is, if you look at the short video I added to my problem, that I want it to start at the left side,..." suggesting that your solution, while on the right lines wasn't exactly what they were looking for.

Comment: I think that's just the same question in other words. The description of the video is exactly how I understood the program should work in the first place. No new information provided there.