# Is there a way to recover my answer to another users deleted question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, specific-answer

A few times I have experienced that I spent time writing an answer to a question only to find that the question was deleted. This seems to cause my answer to simply disappear from the universe.

Is there a way I can still access my answer?

Btw., in those cases I suspect the deletion was done by the user, i.e. [this very annoying behavior](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316117/what-to-do-when-a-question-you-answered-gets-deleted-intentionally).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/deleted-answers/11993121

Comment: Provided the user hasn't received upvotes on their question, then the system will at least take a "dim view" of them deleting their question, and they will likely quickly find themselves on the end of a question ban.

Comment: @Larnu Hopefully, yes. It is really demotivating to honest contributors.

Comment: Sometimes the best solution is to be more choosy as to which questions to answer, to avoid "low hanging fruit" questions of most basic syntax made by new users, which in my experience, are the most frequent types of questions where this happens.

Comment: Related feature request: [How can I retrieve an answer I posted for a question that has been voluntarily removed by the author?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266984/2745495)

Comment: @RyanM https://stackoverflow.com/users/deleted-answers/current works for anyone.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I completely agree and I try to be careful. The question triggering me to write this post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75613672/check-if-tree-is-binary-search-one-with-duplicates-allowed-on-the-left/75614271#75614271). It still looks legitimate to me (and of course, I do not know the reason why the author chose to delete it).

Comment: FYI, the question has now been undeleted.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Thank you.

Comment: @nielsen Can there be any other reason than hiding the evidence for deleting a legitimate question as soon as it is answered?

Comment: @Gimby Simple lack of understanding of how the platform works. "I got my answer, cool, I'll delete the question so it doesn't take up space"... or whatever. Who knows.

Comment: Call me cynical (I am), but as it's not the user's first rodeo (they have multiple questions, where they have accepted an answer as the solution) I'm less inclined to believe it was due to a lack of understanding.

Comment: @Larnu still, it answers my question :) Technically it is possible that a lack of understanding causes it. Truth be told, sometimes I have the idea that some people are just really good at operating in a bubble and not cause any collisions at all. Until that one day they ask for recommendations and then they have to learn the hard meta way that the site actually has rules.